# Aggregation on entire input data - single vs multi partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a daily job , aggregating the data at `user` and `day` level, writing to s3 partition on `year=<>/month=<>/day=<>`. The job runs fine ~30min.

Now, I need to convert above logic to weekly to process 7 days data. ie. aggregate at `user` and `week`, finally write to `year=<>/month=<>/week=<>` folder or `year_month=<>/week=<>` folder.

Input daily data is 600GB, so weekly input parquet data is 3.5 TB.

```
# year_month holds latest year and month, covers cross year/month spills for same week, during year end or month end
df = df.withColumn('year_month', expr("max(concat(year(timestamp_field), lpad(month(timestamp_field), 2, '0'))) over()")) \
      .withColumn('week', weekofyear("timestamp_field"))
```

with above code, job is not running for even 1 days data, job is running 7+ hrs. For 7 days data, job is failing with Stage failed, executor heartbeat timed out.

Question - if we are processing 7 days data (or N number of days) and if we do `expr("max(concat(year(timestamp_field), lpad(month(timestamp_field), 2, '0'))) over()")`, does spark brings entire 7 days data to single partition leading to OOM? or spark can process data in parallel in this case across executors? Is there any way we can avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, because of your window without a partition column, all data is brought to one partition. I think you can convert your query from a window operation to a groupby operation (and then cross-join the result back for example), which may solve your problem.